# can we use MemberFunction type as template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, member-functions

if there's a `class T{ void M() };`, I want to have a template class that can use `T::M` as template parameter. say something like this:

```
T t;
TUser<T::M> user(t);
```

is it possible?

Comment: Why the downvote? Looks like a reasonable, albeit hasty question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, its possible:

```
template< typename T, void (T::*M)() >
struct something
{
    void somewhere( T* obj )
    {
        (obj->*M)();
    }
};
```

and its used like this:

```
T t;
something< T, &T::M > user;
user.somewhere( &t );
```